# access a Properties.Settings via javascript in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

is it possible to access a `Properties.Settings` which I set in my visual studio asp.net project via javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of.  In ASP.NET, you can write these out to the client.  But you cannot change the value from  JavaScript.  To write it out in markup, do:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prop = '<%= Properties.X %>';
</script>
```

I don't use property settings too much.  You would have to use the fully quantified name to be able to refer to it, and it would have to be public for this to work.  If it's not public, you can create a public property on the ASP.NET page, and then have the page return the setting.  Page properties or methods very easily work in this fashion too.

Comment: cant access it via razor @Properties

Comment: Try using the functions block (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2010/07/30/using-functions-in-an-asp-net-page-with-razor-syntax.aspx) and put a public function there that returns the property, see if it's recognized.

Comment: The properties you are referring to are in that project, correct?  They would have to be public for it to work, I believe, so maybe it's the level of accessibility.

Comment: okay this could be my fault. the problem is, some other vars of them can not be public.